# PowerPoint 2010 VSTO Question

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

How do I go next/previos slide from within the addin

Comment: In slideshow mode, or in normal/edit mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As VSTO uses Interop for just about everything (not everything), you can use the samples on MSDN for VSTO-specific solutions. What you want is [`SlideShowView.Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slideshowview.next.aspx) and [`SlideShowView.Previous`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slideshowview.previous.aspx).